# Change direction of axis marks in a barplot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I need the following barplot with special axis marks. I tried for while but have difficulties getting it to work. Especially my axis-labels need to change their direction. I know that I have to use `axTicks`, `axis` and `barplot` commands. Anyone with an idea?

How it should look like:

[image]

Here is my data:

```
bpsamplevalues<-structure(c(21.3389252731795, 18.9930828477016, 19.4378755546201, 
22.1009743407998, 23.8099463895258, 18.9706355343085, 19.4619810121121, 
19.3433394825869, 26.8760997862876, 19.0948710373689), .Names = c("Div 1", 
"Div 2", "Div 3", "Div 4", "Div 5", "Div 6", "Div 7", "Div 8", 
"Div 9", "Div 10"))
```

I started with this code but I can not find a solution to get further:

```
barplot(bpsamplevalues, col="#87DEE1", axes=F, names.arg=F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. It is the `las` argument which sets the orientation of axes labels. See `?par` for more information.

```
barplot(bpsamplevalues, col = "#87DEE1", axes = FALSE, las = 2)
axis(side = 2, tick = FALSE, las = 1)
grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL, col = "white", lty = "solid")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I added the white horizonal lines using the abline command. I also tried it with grid but the positioning of the lines is not correct.

Comment: I have updated `grid` to `ny = NULL`: "When NULL, [...] the grid aligns with the tick marks on the corresponding default axis"